# Question on analytic continuation of functions related to $\log\zeta(s)$ and $\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s)$ that converge for $|\Re(s)|>1$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

Consider the following two Dirichlet series

$$C_3(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N 1_{n=p^k}\, \log(n)\, n^{-s}\right),\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{1}$$

$$K_\Omega(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N 1_{n=p^k}\, \Omega(n)\, n^{-s}\right),\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{2}$$

where $1_{n=p^k}$ is the prime-power indicator function which returns the value $1$ if $n$ is a prime-power and zero otherwise and $\Omega(n)$ counts the number of non-distinct primes in $n$ (i.e. $\Omega(n)=k$ when $n=p^k$).

---

I believe $C_3(s)$ and $K_\Omega(s)$ defined in formulas (1) and (2) above can be analytically continued from $\Re(s)>1$ to $\Re(s)>0$ as follows

$$C_3(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \phi(n)\, \frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(n s))\right),\quad\Re(s)>0\tag{3}$$

$$K_\Omega(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N b(n)\, \log\zeta(n s)\right),\quad\Re(s)>0\tag{4}$$

where $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function and

$$b(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{d|n} d^2\, \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\tag{5}$$

---

Note that $b(n)\, n=\sum\limits_{d|n} d^2\, \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$ corresponds to [OEIS Entry A007434](https://oeis.org/A007434) for the Jordan function $J_2(n)$ which is a generalization of Euler's totient function $\phi(n)$ and

$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N A007434(n)\, n^{-s}\right)=\frac{\zeta(s-2)}{\zeta(s)},\quad\Re(s)>3\tag{6}$$

whereas

$$\underset{\text{N}\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N b(n)\, n^{-s}\right)=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s+1)},\quad\Re(s)>2\tag{7}$$

and

$$\underset{\text{N}\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \phi(n)\, n^{-s}\right)=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)},\quad\Re(s)>2\tag{8}$$

---

I believe $C_3(s)$ and $K_\Omega(s)$ defined in formulas (1) and (2) above can also be evaluated as follows

$$\hat{C}_3(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=2}^N \frac{1_{n\in\mathbb{P}}\, \log(n)}{n^s+n^{-s}-2}\right),\quad|\Re(s)|>1\tag{9}$$

$$\hat{K}_\Omega(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=2}^N \frac{1_{n\in\mathbb{P}}}{n^s+n^{-s}-2}\right),\quad|\Re(s)|>1\tag{10}$$

for $\Re(s)>1$ which is illustrated in Figures (1) to (6) following my questions below where $1_{n\in\mathbb{P}}$ is the prime indicator function which returns the value $1$ if $n$ is a prime and zero otherwise.

---

Note formulas (9) and (10) above for $\hat{C}_3(s)$ and $\hat{K}_\Omega(s)$ converge for $\Re(s)<-1$ as well as $\Re(s)>1$ and evaluate to $\hat{C}_3(-s)$=$\hat{C}_3(s)$ and $\hat{K}_\Omega(-s)$=$\hat{K}_\Omega(s)$ for $|\Re(s)|>1$.

---

> **Question (1)**: Is there a name for functions such as $\hat{C}_3(s)$ and $\hat{K}_\Omega(s)$ defined in formulas (9) and (10) above which converge in the left and right half planes except for a vertical strip between the two?

---

> **Question (2)**: In light of the alternate representation of $C_3(s)$ and $K_\Omega(s)$ defined in formulas (1) and (2) above for $\Re(s)>1$ via $\hat{C}_3(s)$ and $\hat{K}_\Omega(s)$ defined in formulas (9) and (10) above, does it make sense to talk about the analytic continuation of $C_3(s)$ and $K_\Omega(s)$ defined in formula (3) and (4) above from $\Re(s)>0$ to $\Re(s)<0$ via the functional equations $C_3(-s)$=$C_3(s)$ and $K_\Omega(-s)$=$K_\Omega(s)$ even though they would be undefined along the imaginary axis where $\Re(s)=0$?

---

> **Question (3)**: Assuming the answer to question (2) above is no, does this imply $\hat{C}_3(s)$ and $\hat{K}_\Omega(s)$ defined in formulas (9) and (10) must be treated as different functions than $C_3(s)$ and $K_\Omega(s)$ defined in formulas (1) to (4) above in which case they might have an analytic continuation from $|\Re(s)|>1$ to the entire complex plane including the imaginary axis where $\Re(s)=0$ with the functional equations $\hat{C}_3(-s)$=$\hat{C}_3(s)$ and $\hat{K}_\Omega(-s)$=$\hat{K}_\Omega(s)$?

---

It's a bit unclear to me how analytic continuation and its uniqueness apply to the formulas in this question (see [Initial discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation#Initial_discussion) under the Wikipedia article on Analytic continuation) since $|\Re(s)<1|$ does not represent a connected domain and neither does $\Re(s)\ne 0$.

---

The following three figures illustrate formulas (1) and (3) for $C_3(s)$ above in orange and blue and formula (9) for $\hat{C}_3(s)$ above in green where formula (3) is evaluated at $K=100$ and formulas (1) and (9) are both evaluated at $K=1000$. Formula (3) for $C_3(s)$ is used as a reference function as I believe it converges more rapidly than the related Dirichlet series defined in formula (1) which is one of the reasons a lower evaluation limit is used for formula (3), and another reason is the terms of formula (3) take much longer to evaluate than the terms of formulas (1) and (9).

---

[image: Illustration of formulas (1), (3), and (9) for real s]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formulas (1) and (3) for $C_3(s)$ (orange and blue) and formula (9) for $\hat{C}_3(s)$ (green) evaluated for real $s$

---

[image: Illustration of real part of formulas (1), (3), and (9) for s=3/2+i t]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of real part of formulas (1) and (3) for $C_3(s)$ (orange and blue) and formula (9) for $\hat{C}_3(s)$ (green) evaluated along the line $s=\frac{3}{2}+i t$

---

[image: Illustration of imaginary part of formulas (1), (3), and (9) for s=3/2+i t]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of imaginary part of formulas (1) and (3) for $C_3(s)$ (orange and blue) and formula (9) for $\hat{C}_3(s)$ (green) evaluated along the line $s=\frac{3}{2}+i t$

---

The following three figures illustrate formulas (2) and (4) for $K_\Omega(s)$ above in orange and blue and formula (10) for $\hat{K}_\Omega(s)$ above in green where formula (4) is evaluated at $K=100$ and formulas (2) and (10) are both evaluated at $K=1000$. Formula (4) for $K_\Omega(s)$ is used as a reference function as I believe it converges more rapidly than the related Dirichlet series defined in formula (2) which is one of the reasons a lower evaluation limit is used for formula (4), and another reason is the terms of formula (4) take much longer to evaluate than the terms of formulas (2) and (10).

---

Figure (4) below only illustrates formula (4) where it evaluates as strictly real which is for $s>1$ because Mathematica's evaluation of $\log\zeta(s)$ has an imaginary part for $0<s<1$ due to the branch cut of $\log(s)$ along the negative real axis.

---

[image: Illustration of formulas (2), (4), and (10) for real s]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of formulas (2) and (4) for $K_\Omega(s)$ (orange and blue) and formula (10) for $\hat{K}_\Omega(s)$ (green) evaluated for real $s$

---

[image: Illustration of real part of formulas (2), (4), and (10) for s=3/2+i t]

**Figure (5)**: Illustration of real part of formulas (2) and (4) for $K_\Omega(s)$ (orange and blue) and formula (10) for $\hat{K}_\Omega(s)$ (green) evaluated along the line $s=\frac{3}{2}+i t$

---

[image: Illustration of imaginary part of formulas (2), (4), and (10) for s=3/2+i t]

**Figure (6)**: Illustration of imaginary part of formulas (2) and (4) for $K_\Omega(s)$ (orange and blue) and formula (10) for $\hat{K}_\Omega(s)$ (green) evaluated along the line $s=\frac{3}{2}+i t$